# Xcode ViewController Not Showing in Custom Class

Tags: xcode

I just started learning about Xcode, i follow the tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOBUiZwQpvE

There is a part where you need to put in the Custom Class in the main_iphone.storyboard

But I can't seem to find ViewController. And I tried to input manually, but the software wouldn't allow me to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spent 4 hours on this issue this evening. Reproduced on Xcode 7beta5 and Xcode 6.4 with a stock single-view App. Turned out Xcode is *very* unhappy about storing Projects **within DropBox**. It all magically went away once I moved everything outside of the DropBox tree.

Amazingly, I have not seen this solution proposed anywhere yet.

Answer (score 3):

I was pulling my hair out for days on this and then stumbled upon someone's solution that worked:

1. Product -> Clean
2. Close XCode
3. Remove all items in the /Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ folder (location may differ, thanks Julian).
4. Restart your computer (this seems to be the key to it)

Comment: Clean + Clear will do it. The DerivedData is not guarantied to be saved in this location. I have it relative to project the location for example